# NullReferenceException when inserting records

Tags: vb.net, textbox, nullreferenceexception, autofill

I am working on a table that allows users to insert new records to a database. I have 2 fields named PartNumber and I have code-behind that autofills the second (and keeps it readonly) based on what's being typed in the first textbox. I have this so far:

```
Protected Sub PartNumChange(ByVal sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim str As String
    str = Me.ToString()
        DetailsView1A.DataItem("PrimaryKey5") = str
End Sub
```

But I keep getting a NullReferenceException. I'm okay with this since all the fields are blank/null when the insert button in DetailsView is clicked anyways.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: add a null check validation

Comment: Which object is `null`?  `DetailsView1A`?  Something else?  If it's possible for an object to be `null` in this case then you'll need to check for the presence of `null` (`Nothing` in VB, I think) and handle it accordingly.

Comment: As in a try catch statement? What would I put in the catch though? Sorry, I haven't touched vb in a few years